# In linux, how to use python to check whether an external program is running?

Tags: python, linux

In linux, how to use python to check whether an external non-system program is running? Is there a standard module for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/), e.g.

```
import psutil

def check_if_running(name):
    for ps in psutil.process_iter():
        if ps.name == name:
            return True
    return False

check_if_running('python')
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be interested in [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/). Otherwise you could invoke *pgrep* using the *subprocess* library.